# VB Converting Lenght from Imperial to Metric

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hello I'm attempting to convert Inches to Centimeters, Miles and Feet convert correctly but the centimeters returns a value of 0. Any advice on why I might be having this problem?

```
Dim totalInches, totalMeters As Long
    Dim km, m As Double
    Dim cm As Decimal
    Dim result As String

    totalInches = 63360 * miles + 36 * yards + 12 * feet + inches
    totalMeters = totalInches / 39.37
    km = Int(totalMeters / 1000)
    m = Int(totalMeters - (km * 1000))
    cm = (totalMeters - (km * 1000) - m) * 100

    result = "The Metric Length is:" + vbNewLine _
        + km.ToString + " Kilometers" + vbNewLine _
        + m.ToString + " Meters" + vbNewLine _
        + cm.ToString + " Centimeters"
```

Comment: In VB `+` is for math and `&` is for concatenating strings.

Comment: As your code currently stands, `miles`, `yards`, `feet` and `inches` are all undeclared so this won't even compile. If they are declared somewhere else but not set then your ouput will be 0.

Comment: @OneFineDay: VB .net allows either, try it: `Dim a As String = "abc" Dim b As String = "def" Debug.Print(a + b)`

Comment: @TheBlueDog what vb allows and what is wise to do are two different things `Dim a = "21" Dim b = 21 Dim c = a + b` (Option Strict Off)

Comment: @Steve: True, I never said it was wise though. ;)

Comment: @Steve: Anyway, who uses `Option Strict Off`? Oh, wait ...

Comment: OneFineDay thank you for the information using & instead of +.

Comment: TheBlueDog I have those variables declared in the function parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Long integer when you make your division between the totalInches and the constant 39.37. This effectively truncates the decimal part of the result.

Of course you would never have had this error if you had used `Option Strict On` on your project properties because your code would not compile.

In either case you need two changes

```
Public Function ConvertImperialToMetric(miles as Integer, yards as Integer, feet as Integer, inches as Integer) as String

    Dim totalInches as Long

    ' totalMeters should be a double
    Dim totalMeters As Double
    Dim km, m As Double
    Dim cm As Double
    Dim result As String

    totalInches = 63360 * miles + 36 * yards + 12 * feet + inches

    ' With totalMeters as Double you don't loose the decimal part of the division
    totalMeters = totalInches / 39.37
    km = Int(totalMeters / 1000)
    m = Int(totalMeters - (km * 1000))
    cm = (totalMeters - (km * 1000) - m) * 100

    result = "The Metric Length is:" + vbNewLine _
        + km.ToString + " Kilometers" + vbNewLine _
        + m.ToString + " Meters" + vbNewLine _
        + cm.ToString + " Centimeters"    
    return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, I appreciate your help. I also thank you for the advice on turning Option Strict to ON.